# Jira filter REST consumption

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Is there a way to consume Jira filters with RESTful webservices?
I am trying to consume Jira filter from Java but not finding a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the API has methods which are all documented very well in the [JIRA REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/filter). Though the doc version I linked describes a Server instance's API it also applies for Cloud instances - all the `/filter/*` endpoints are enabled there, too.